# Students t-test

Tags: t-test, descriptive-statistics, t-distribution

In comparing B6 levels in serum vs plasma, 20 volunteers were chosen. The objective is to determine if B6 concentrations differ when taking from serum or plasma. Each volunteer gave two samples, one for plasma, one for serum.

The results were listed and as sample number e.g. 1, and corresponding serum and plasma [B6].

What would be the best way to analyse this? I'm thinking an **independent** t-test to test the difference between mean B6 in serum and plasma? However, would a paired t-test make more sense, given that each volunteer gives one for plasma and serum?

Comment: I think a paired test is more appropriate since serum and plasma are from the same person and thus not independent.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, a paired t-test is the way to go here. This is because your observations are not independent, but are grouped in pairs according to the volunteers who gave the samples. A paired t-test allow to exclude variability in B6 levels between volunteers, and test only within-volunteer variability (serum vs plasma).

Note that a paired t-test ultimately amounts to a one-sample t-test of the within subjects differences (B6 levels in serum minus B6 levels in plasma). The null hypothesis of the paired t-test is that the average within-subject difference is 0.

Comment: Ok, appreciate the help. Would a Wilcoxon signed test be applicable as a replacement test? Or is there a different alternative?

Comment: Yes, but this depends on how your data are distributed. If it is reasonable to assume that your data (B6 levels in the population) are normally distributed, parametric tests like the paired t-test are considered to have more power. If you cannot assume that, then you cannot use the t-test; but you can still use non-parametric tests like the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.